Euler Lagrange Equation - clarification of a step in the derivation.
I'm trying to understand the formal justification of the step $\frac{\partial L}{\partial y_\epsilon}\Big|_{\epsilon=0} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial y}$, as appears in the picture attached to the question below (note - $y_\epsilon = y + \epsilon h(x)$).
My line of thought is the following:
$\frac{\partial L}{\partial y_\epsilon} = \lim_{a \to 0} \frac{L(x, y_\epsilon + a, y'_\epsilon) - L(x, y_\epsilon, y'_\epsilon)}{a}$
Upon setting $\epsilon=0$ we have (substitute $\epsilon=0$ into the above limit):
$\frac{\partial L}{\partial y_\epsilon}\Big|_{\epsilon=0} = \lim_{a \to 0} \frac{L(x, y + a, y') - L(x, y, y')}{a} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial y}$
Is it the rigorous explanation?
Thank you in advance



There are several ways to verify this result, but your reasoning is correct.

Yes. This relies on $\frac{\partial L }{\partial y}$ being continuous, which is usually true for these problem.
